# What is a good way to `update_or_initialize_with` in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid5

Each user has one address.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_one :address
end

class Address
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :user

  field :street_name, type:String
end

u = User.find(...)
u.address.update(street_name: 'Main St')
```

If we have a User without an Address, this will fail.

So, is there a good (built-in) way to do `u.address.update_or_initialize_with`?

Mongoid 5

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with ruby. But I think I understand the problem. Your schema might looks like this.

```
user = {
   _id : user1234,
   address: address789
} 

address = {
   _id: address789,
   street_name: ""
   user: user1234
}

//in mongodb(javascript), you can get/update address of user this way
u = User.find({_id: user1234})
u.address //address789
db.address.update({user: u.address}, {street_name: "new_street name"})

//but since the address has not been created, the variable u does not even have property address.
u.address = undefined
```

Perhaps you can try to just create and attached it manually like this:

```
 #create an address document, to get _id of this address
 address = address.insert({street_name: "something"}); 

 #link or attached it to u.address
 u.update({address: address._id})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently. There is a built in way but it differs from active records' `#find_or_initialize_by` or `#find_or_create_by` method.

In my case, I needed to bulk insert records and update or create if not found, but I believe the same technique can be used even if you are not bulk inserting.

```
# returns an array of query hashes:
def update_command(users)
  updates = []
  users.each do |user|
    updates << { 'q' => {'user_id' => user._id},
                 'u' => {'address' => 'address'},
                 'multi' => false,
                 'upsert' => true }
  end
  { update: Address.collection_name.to_s, updates: updates, ordered: false }
end

def bulk_update(users)
  client = Mongoid.default_client
  command = bulk_command(users)
  client.command command
  client.close
end
```

since your not bulk updating, assuming you have a foreign key field called `user_id` in your Address collection. You might be able to:

```
Address.collection.update({ 'q' => {'user_id' => user._id},
                            'u' => {'address' => 'address'},
                            'multi' => false,
                            'upsert' => true }
```

which will match against the `user_id`, update the given fields when found (`address` in this case) or create a new one when not found.

For this to work, there is 1 last crucial step though.
You must add an index to your Address collection with a special flag.

The field you are querying on (`user_id` in this case)
must be indexed with a flag of either `{ unique: true }` 
or `{ sparse: true }`. the `unique` flag will raise an error
if you have 2 or more nil `user_id` fields. The `sparse` option wont.
Use that if you think you may have nil values.

access your mongo db through the terminal

1. `show dbs`
2. `use your_db_name`
   check if the addresses collection already has the index you are looking for
3. `db.addresses.getIndexes()`
   if it already has an index on user_id, you may want to remove it
   `db.addresses.dropIndex( { user_id: 1} )`
   and create  it again with the following flag:
4. `db.addresses.createIndex( { user_id: 1}, { sparse: true } )`

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

EDIT #1

There seems to have changes in Mongoid 5.. instead of `User.collection.update` you can use `User.collection.update_one`

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/

The docs show you need a `filter` rather than a `query` as first argument but they seem to be the same..

```
Address.collection.update_one( { user_id: user_id },
  '$set' => { "address": 'the_address', upsert: true} )
```

PS:
If you only write `{ "address": 'the_address' }` as your update clause without including an `update operator` such as `$set`, the whole document will get overwritten rather than updating just the `address` field.

EDIT#2

About why you may want to index with `unique` or `sparse`

If you look at the `upsert` section in the link bellow, you will see:

> To avoid multiple upserts, ensure that the filter fields are uniquely
>   indexed.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/

Comment: Because you will match against that key to either `update` if found or `insert` if not found. If you don't have a unique or sparse index, you can still update the first matching document or update all matching documents with the `{ multi: true }` flag.

Please see edit #2.